# Getting "error": "<expression>,<operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected got '('"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hql

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate is showing me an error:

> `<expression>,<operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected got '('`

right under a braket inside a HQL statement which apperently is not a problem for compilation or runtime.

```java
@Query("SELECT offer FROM OfferEntity offer " +
        "   JOIN offer.placeOwnership AS owner " +
        "   JOIN owner.place AS place " +
        "WHERE " +
        "   place.id = :placeId AND " +
        "   to_char(offer.dayFrom, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = :offerDate AND " +
                   ^
        <expression>,<operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected got '('
        "   offer.repeating = false")
List<OfferEntity> getAllForDate(@Param("placeId") Long placeId, @Param("offerDate") String offerDate);
```

Any idea why this is the case and how to get rid of this? It's annoying and missleading (presumably since the code is working).

[image]

Comment: `toChar()` is not an HQL function.

Comment: @Andreas Hm, but why does it work then? Is this a native call then (PostgreSQL)?

Comment: Because the implementation that handles the `@Query` might allow native methods, even if the standard doesn't, and IntelliJ might syntax check against the standard for you.

Comment: Assuming `offer.dayFrom` is a pure-date value in the database, it would be better the change to `offer.dayFrom = :offerDate` and make `offerDate` a `java.sql.Date` value (or `LocalDate`).

Comment: @Andreas Hm, if I do that I get `Parameter value [2018-10-08] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]` - but do I really want to use `java.util.Date`?

Comment: @Andreas Alright, got it - had to fix that in my entity too! Now it works without `to_char`  - thanks for the hint! It's unfortunate that IntelliJ can't warn about that - but I get it - in that case it would have to understand all dialects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query -> In 2.2 Native

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM USERS u WHERE u.status = 1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
```

is worked for us. You need to add "value = " and ",
nativeQuery = true" inside the @Query

Comment: What about [JPQL](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)?

Comment: @Robert What about it? You and I gave same link, could you please give more detail about your "what about" question.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers is the correct one! Since it doesn't answer the main question.
In the question, the problem is not compiling the JPQL/HQL ( As such functions are already implemented now in hibernate's dialects via registerFunction ) to convert it to native, But is how to remove the wrong IntelliJ inspection error.